# Calling Wrapper Function From Javascript is Crashing App - React-Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

Hello I am trying to call a function in javascript that I am exporting via Objective C. When I call my function in javascript my app is crashing.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getModelAsync:()
                  resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  NSError *error;
  NSString *contents = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];

  if (contents) {
    resolve(contents);
  } else {
    reject(@"Test", @"Something is broken",error);
  }
}
```

Its failing on this on the if statement with this Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

```
if (!RCTIsIdentifierHead(**input)) {
  return NO;
```

All help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: I've run into something similar, did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue today and managed to solved it. It looks like the function argument types aren't matching up. This error seems to be triggered, when the function types aren't compatible. Something like the following code snippet, would trigger this error, because a dictionary is not compatible with type string and thus the function argument cannot be correctly cast.

**Module.m**

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(myFunction: (NSDictionary)options)
```

**Module.swift**

```
@objc
func myFunction(_ options: String) -> Void {
  ...
}
```

To fix it, make sure you are doing something like this:

**FixedModule.m**

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(myFunction: (NSDictionary)options)
```

**FixedModule.swift**

```
@objc
func myFunction(_ options: NSDictionary) -> Void {
  ...
}
```

I hope this helps!